# how to use guice correctly for dependency inject in java servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, guice, guice-servlet

sorry for the bad question title... 
Disclaimer: Not much experience around web-apps, primarily used dropwizard.

So i have been trying to use guice in my java web-app
Initially without guice, servlets were serving the api correctly but after configuring servlet to be served from guice for below endpoint,

```
http://localhost:8080/myServlets/test
```

I am getting below error:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Type Status Report
>
> Message The requested resource [/myServlets/test] is not available
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
> for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.57

with below stacktrace:

```
16-Sep-2020 11:33:43.941 INFO [AsyncFileHandlerWriter-2008362258] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.google.inject.internal.util.LineNumbers$LineNumberReader]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.google.inject.internal.util.LineNumbers$LineNumberReader]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1378)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1366)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1218)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
        at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements$1.load(StackTraceElements.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements$1.load(StackTraceElements.java:45)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3976)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4960)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4966)
        at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements.forMember(StackTraceElements.java:71)
        at com.google.inject.internal.Messages.formatParameter(Messages.java:286)
        at com.google.inject.internal.Messages.formatInjectionPoint(Messages.java:273)
        at com.google.inject.internal.Messages.formatSource(Messages.java:229)
        at com.google.inject.internal.Messages.formatSource(Messages.java:220)
        at com.google.inject.internal.Messages.formatMessages(Messages.java:90)
        at com.google.inject.ConfigurationException.getMessage(ConfigurationException.java:73)
        at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:396)
        at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:485)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:837)
        at org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter$IndentingPrintWriter.println(OneLineFormatter.java:298)
        at java.base/java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter.println(Throwable.java:768)
        at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:659)
        at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:725)
        at org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter.format(OneLineFormatter.java:171)
        at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.publish(FileHandler.java:291)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.publishInternal(AsyncFileHandler.java:146)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler$LogEntry.flush(AsyncFileHandler.java:185)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler$LoggerThread.run(AsyncFileHandler.java:161)
```

Tried [Guice Git](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted) but `createInjector` part stumps me as there is no `main` method.

Reference code is below, any help is appreciated!

**CacheService**

```
public interface CacheService {
    public abstract String hello();
}
```

**CacheServiceImpl**

```
import com.google.inject.Provides;

public class CacheServiceImpl implements CacheService {

    @Provides
    public String hello() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

**CacheModule**

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

public class CacheModule extends AbstractModule {

    protected void configure() {
        bind(CacheService.class).to(CacheServiceImpl.class);
    }
}
```

**MyGuiceServletConfig**

```
public class MyGuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new ServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                serve("/*").with(ResourceServlet.class);
                bind(CacheModule.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**ResourceServlet**

```
@Slf4j
@Path("/")
@Singleton
public class ResourceServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Context
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Inject
    public ResourceServlet(CacheService storageModule) throws JAXBException {
          log.info("base {}", storageModule.hello());
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Product abc() {
        log.info("servletContext {}", servletContext);
        
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>myServlets</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Inject Guice -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.myorg.application.guice.MyGuiceServletConfig</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: The first thing noticed is that instead of `bind(CacheModule.class)` you should be including it in your `Guice.createInjector(new CacheModule(), new ServletModule() {})` or `install(new CacheModule())`

Comment: @kendavidson: tried your suggestion but still the same, commented out my `serve` in injector. app runs now but servlet resource turns `404` as there is no path resolution, can you help me understand a bit more please? how do i `serve` my resources?

Comment: @kendavidson: update, `return Guice.createInjector(new CacheModule(), new ServletModule() { @Override  protected void configureServlets() {serve("/*").with(ResourceServlet.class);}});`

did this and now api being served is via `doGet` and not actual `jersey` resource. i.e., `/test` is not serving the content but `protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException` is.

any way to restore back jersey?

Comment: I'll be honest, I haven't used Jersey at all, but if it's like RESTEasy you need to implement your Guice Modules into an extension of the Jersey configuration/dispatch servlet.  GuiceFilter looks like it strictly for basic Servlets. Found this which shows how to do so:  http://www.zakariaamine.com/2017-12-11/how-to-use-guice-jersey-2

Comment: no worries, will figure out. one last question, how do i inject `ServletContext`? `@Context` annotation doesn't work i see here!! Thank you so much for you help so far! :)

Comment: Maybe look into https://github.com/Squarespace/jersey2-guice it looks like it's got a bunch of support, although I don't see `@Context`.  But you should be able to override `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) ` and use that to create a binding.

Comment: @kendavidson: took some pointers and dropped `jersey`, integrated full fledged `restEasy` as it _felt more native_ towards tomcat / jboss / glassfish eco system and jersey + hk2 bridge solution felt more of a _hack_ . `ServletContextEvent` is still a mystery though, is this your forte now via `restEasy`!? :\

Comment: If you're on resteasy now, you should have access `@Context` as a method parameter for you `Api/Controller` level classes.  You don't need to go so far as `ServletContextEvent` I was just referencing that as a way to initialize your bindings for `ServletContext` (when using Jersey).

Comment: i have it in my Api but thats not where it is needed. may i request you to have a look at this fresh question related to it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986297/how-to-inject-servlet-context-in-guice-module), i have explained it better there