# how to inject servlet context in guice module?

Tags: java, guice, resteasy, servletcontextlistener

sorry for the bad question title... 
Disclaimer: Not much experience around web-apps, primarily used dropwizard.

So i have been trying to use guice in my java web-app

I have servletContext in my servlet / resource file but i need to have it *injected* in my guice module, how to inject servlet context in guice module?

Reference code is below, any help is appreciated!

**CacheService**

```
public interface CacheService {
    public abstract String hello();
}
```

**CacheServiceImpl**

```
public class CacheServiceImpl implements CacheService {
JedisPool jedisPool = null;

@Context
private ServletContext servletContext;

@Provides
public String hello() {
    log.info("CacheServiceImpl servletContext {}", servletContext); //  this is null
    return "hello world";
}


@Provides
public Jedis getJedisConnection() {
    HostAndPort redisServer = HostAndPortUtil.getRedisServers().get(0);
    if (jedisPool == null)
        jedisPool = new JedisPool(getJedisPoolConfig(), redisServer.getHost(),
                redisServer.getPort(), Protocol.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
                servletContext.getInitParameter("REDIS_PSWD")); // sample example of servletContext requirement, there are other functions in this module which need context 
    return jedisPool.getResource();
}
```

}

**CacheModule**

```
public class CacheModule implements Module{

    public void configure(final Binder binder) {
        binder.bind(ResourceServlet.class);
        binder.bind(CacheService.class).to(CacheServiceImpl.class);
    }
}
```

**ResourceServlet**

```
@Slf4j
@Path("/")
@Singleton
public class ResourceServlet {

    @Context
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Inject
    public ResourceServlet(CacheService storageModule) throws JAXBException {
          log.info("base {}", storageModule.hello());
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Product abc() {
        log.info("servletContext {}", servletContext); // this is not null but how do i pass it on to module?
        
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.guice.modules</param-name>
    <param-value>com.org.app.guice.CacheModule</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: `ServletContext` is a little different, you need to inject the implementation yourself - you'll need to extend `GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener` and add it to your module `new CacheModuleImpl(context)` yourself.  Look at the very last section https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.21.Final/userguide/html/Guice1.html#d4e2273